# How to create a custom student group and add students to that group?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a student project management system and each student will have a group with project. Only the admin will be able to add the students to the specific group using a drop down list menu. So far, I have create a student model and a group model such as these.

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.IntegerField(max_length=11,primary_key=True)
    course_taken = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    area_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True) 
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.user.first_name and self.user.last_name:
            full_name = self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name
        return full_name 

class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    members = models.OneToManyField(User,through='Student')
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project,null=True)
```

How to continue from this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

As seen in this example you can do that via Model-Relationship (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many).
I would suggest consulting the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create create three different class to do that task. With the Enrollment class the admin will be able to add the students to the specific group.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Enrollment')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_enrolled = models.DateField()
    final_grade = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['student', 'course']]
```